# How to change to week and days according to current views

Tags: reactjs, react-big-calendar

I am customizing react big calendar toolbar, and it's working fine for switching month, but the issue is i am unable to switch week and days according to the current views.
In every views next , prev button change the month.
This is custom toolbar for navigating

```
const CustomToolbar = (toolbar, open, setOpen) => {
  const goToBack = () => {
    toolbar.date.setMonth(toolbar.date.getMonth() - 1);
    toolbar.onNavigate("prev");
  };
  const goToNext = () => {
    toolbar.onNavigate("next");
    toolbar.date.setDays(toolbar.date.getDay() + 1);
    //i want to change the dates state according to current view 
   
  };
  const goToWeekView = () => {
    toolbar.onView("week");
  };
  const goToMonthView = () => {
    toolbar.onView("month");
  };
  const goToDayView = () => {
    toolbar.onView("day");
  };
  const goToAgendaView = () => {
    toolbar.onView("agenda");
  };
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Box className="back-next-buttons">
        <Stack direction="row" alignItems="center">
          <IconButton onClick={goToBack} className="btn-back">
            <ArrowBackIosIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography
            onClick={goToCurrent}          >
            Today
          </Typography>

          <IconButton onClick={goToNext} className="btn-back">
            <ArrowForwardIosIcon/>
          </IconButton>
        </Stack>
      </Box>
      {/* date label */}
      <Typography>
        {label()}
      </Typography>
      {/* view buttons */}
      <Stack direction="row" flexWrap="wrap" alignItems="center">
        <SmallButton
          onClick={goToWeekView}
          label="Week"/>
        <SmallButton
          onClick={goToMonthView}
          label="Month"/>
        <SmallButton
          onClick={goToDayView}
          label="Day"/>
        <SmallButton
          onClick={goToAgendaView}
          label="All Events"/>
      </Stack>
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "to switch week and days according to the current views". Please further brief me on what you are accomplishing.

Comment: @AdamTuraj i mean when i was in week view , and when i am navigating to next  or previous, it is changing whole month instead of changing week.

Comment: From what I see in the code you posted, you will always be updating the month when going forward, and day when going back. Unless I am missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building custom components for Big Calendar it is helpful to look at the source code of the actual components, or of components used in the documentation. Looking [at the source](https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/blob/master/stories/props/customComponents/CustomToolbar.component.js) of the custom toolbar in the components prop, you'll see that the toolbar is passed the internal `onNavigate` method, and uses the exported `{navigate}` constants to help you navigate to the proper views.

The internal `onNavigate` method is not well documented (yet), but is very easy to work with.

```js
const today = () => onNavigate(navigate.TODAY);
const next = () => onNavigate(navigate.NEXT);
const previous = () => onNavigate(navigate.PREVIOUS);
// must be JS Date, and only if controlling `date` prop
const toThisDay = (newDate) => onNavigate(navigate.DATE, newDate);
```

If you happen to be controlling `view` and `date` in the same method, then setting both simultaneously can be a challenge due to the internal logic of `onView` and state rerendering, and may require you to wait a tic between setting each variable.

```js
const toThisDay = (newDate) => {
  onView('day');
  window.setTimeout(() => {
    onNavigate(navigate.DATE, newDate);
  }, 100);
};
```